# Concatenate avoiding NAs to produce multiline variable

Tags: r, dataframe, concatenation, missing-data

#### Fake data

```
Fruit <- c("Tomato", "Banana", "Kiwi", "Pear")
Colour <- c("Red", "Yellow", NA, "Green")
Weight <- c(10, 12, 6, 8)

dd <- data.frame(Fruit, Colour, Weight)
```

#### Failed attempt

```
dd <- dd %>%
  mutate(Description = sprintf("%s: %s \n%s: %s \n%s: %s",
                               names(dd)[1], Fruit,
                               names(dd)[2], Colour,
                               names(dd)[3], Weight))

dd$Description[1]
```

#### Desired output: *Multi-line* "Description" variable ignoring NAs.

"Description" variable of Tomato:

```
Fruit: Tomato
Colour: Red
Weight: 10
```

"Description" variable of Kiwi, NA ignored!

```
Fruit: Kiwi
Weight: 6
```

Comment: I think you mixed up kiwi with apricot in your sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through rows, remove NAs, and paste:

```
dd$Description <- unlist(
  apply(dd, 1, function(i) {
    x <- na.omit(i)
    paste(paste0(names(x),":", x), collapse = "\n")
  }))

dd
#    Fruit Colour Weight                            Description
# 1 Tomato    Red     10    Fruit:Tomato\nColour:Red\nWeight:10
# 2 Banana Yellow     12 Fruit:Banana\nColour:Yellow\nWeight:12
# 3   Kiwi   <NA>      6                  Fruit:Kiwi\nWeight: 6
# 4   Pear  Green      8    Fruit:Pear\nColour:Green\nWeight: 8
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could we get "Description" as multi line? \n doesn't seem to be playing its function.

Comment: @user3262756 It is multi-line try: `cat(dd$Description)`

Comment: Yes, thanks so much! Exactly what I needed to do. I select this answer because when viewing the new variable "Description" we don't get a blank space in NAs position.

Answer (score 1):

This feels a bit hackish, but for a base R solution we can use `ifelse` and `is.na` to conditionally either render an attribute, or just empty string:

```
sprintf("%s\n%s\n%s",
    ifelse(is.na(Fruit), "", paste0(names(dd)[1], ": ", Fruit)),
    ifelse(is.na(Colour), "", paste0(names(dd)[2], ": ", Colour)),
    ifelse(is.na(Weight), "", paste0(names(dd)[3], ": ", Weight)))

[1] "Fruit: Tomato\nColour: Red\nWeight: 10"
[2] "Fruit: Banana\nColour: Yellow\nWeight: 12"
[3] "Fruit: Kiwi\n\nWeight: 6"                   <-- Kiwi has no colour
[4] "Fruit: Pear\nColour: Green\nWeight: 8"
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but is it there any way of getting a variable formatted as multi line?

Comment: @user3262756 Not sure what you mean here.  The output in my code snippet about already is multiline, because the text is separated by `\n`.